# Connecting a Wii to a HD TV using coloured pins

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

This is the back of my Philips LED HD TV:

[image: TV sockets]

The sockets are dark blue, yellow and aqua-blue. My Wii has Red, White and Yellow pins.

I have tried all combinations of connecting the Pins in different sockets but I always get "No Video signal" on the TV.

Can some one help me fix this please?

Comment: From what I can tell, the only video input on that thing is the Y/Pb/Pr.  And even that doesn't look right.  What's with the yellow paint everywhere?

Comment: I just scratched yellow chalk over the letters to make them visible in photograph

Comment: I don't get what's unclear about this, voting to reopen

Comment: Something looks strange here. Y/Pb/Pr indicates component inputs, but those have 3 inputs for picture and 2 for sound, while in the picture there's only 3 inputs (and miscoloured, if we suppose they're for component). Also, the labels on the first two indicate both audio and video input. I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the TV doesn't have the Red, White & Yellow sockets located elsewhere, you won't be able to use it

Those sockets are for component, not standard definition

If you have a SCART socket though and have [one of these around](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Scart-Adaptor-Phono-Sockets-Audio/dp/B000L1LY58/ref=sr_1_2/276-6244860-9213942?s=electronics-accessories&ie=UTF8&qid=1403961151&sr=1-2) you will be able to use it. Otherwise you can use a [converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007PY3ZPG) to allow it to play through a HDMI socket, for around $20.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rainbows' suggestions, you can also buy a Red/Yellow/White to HDMI converter (which every HDTV has). They are just somewhat (well a LOT) more expensive:

- [eBay](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/AV-input-RCA-Analog-Audio-Video-Composite-CVBS-to-HDMI-Digital-Output-Converter-/141249513520?pt=AU_Television_Accessories&hash=item20e3208830&_uhb=1)
- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032HU8NM)

It just isn't possible with the input sockets you photographed.

Comment: Just added this lad, but good minds think alike :D

Comment: Hehe, +1'd you :)

Comment: back at you my man

Comment: Thanks guys... I am new here and do not have enough reputations to give an up to you both